# jqgrid search toolbar not coming up using jquery.jqgrid.js

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to add the search bar with jquery.jqgrid.js after trying several methods this method was the only one that did not give me an error but neither does it show my search toolbar, can someone have a look and see if I missing anything??

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Edit', 'AlertId', 'Policy', 'PolicyRule', 'Alert Status',
                   'Alert Code', 'Message', 'Category'],
        colModel: [
      { name: 'Edit', edittype: 'select', formatter: 'showlink' },
      { name: 'AlertId', index: 'AlertId', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int',
        autoFit: true, align: 'left', hidden: true },
      { name: 'Policy', index: 'Policy.Name', sortable: true, sorttype: 'text',
        autoFit: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] },
        align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Policy Rule', index: 'PolicyRule', sortable: true,
        sorttype: 'text', autoFit: true, sorttype: 'text',
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Alert Status', index: 'AlertStatus.status', sortable: true,
        sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] },
        autoFit: true, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Alert Code', index: 'Code', sortable: true, sorttype: 'text',
        align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] },
        autoFit: true },
      { name: 'Message', index: 'Message', sortable: true, sorttype: 'text',
        align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] },
        autoFit: true },
      { name: 'Category', index: 'Category.name', sortable: true,
        sorttype: 'text', align: 'left', autoFit: true,
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }}],
        pager: $("#pager"),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 60, 100],
        scroll: true,
        sortname: 'AlertId',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/basic/images',
        caption: 'my name',
        gridComplete: function() {
            var objRows = $("#list tr");
            var objHeader = $("#list.jqgfirstrow td");
            if (objRows.length > 1) {
                var objFirstRowColumns = $(objRows[1]).children("td");
                for (i = 0; i < objFirstRowColumns.length; i++) {
                    $(objFirstRowColumns[i]).css("width",
                                                 $(objHeader[i]).css("width"));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}); 

$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                  {edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true}); 
$("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",
                  {caption:"Toggle",title:"Toggle Search Toolbar",
                   buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',         
                   onClickButton:function() {                 
                       $("#list")[0].toggleToolbar()
                   } });
$("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",
                  { caption: "Clear", title: "Clear Search",
                    buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
                    onClickButton:function(){                 
                        $("#list")[0].clearToolbar()
                    } });
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
```

Answer (score 0):

After the improving of the format of your code one can see your main error: you call `navGrid`, `navButtonAdd` and `filterToolbar` **outside** of `jQuery(document).ready`. If you move it inside the `jQuery(document).ready` you will see immediately the searching toolbar: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Sue.htm).

You code has other small problems:

1. variable `i` inside `gridComplete` should be declared to be local and not global variable.
2. You should remove deprecated parameter `imgpath`.
3. You use many options of `colModel` parameters with default values like `sortable:true`, `sorttype: 'text'`, `align: 'left'` and so on. It makes only the code longer, slowly and more difficult to read. I recommend you to look in [the part of documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) which describes `colModel` parameters and remove default properties.
4. The `sorttype` property which you use will not work in case of usage `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce:true`. So you should decide either you use server based sorting, paging and filtering/searching and you should better remove in the case `sorttype` properties or you should use `loadonce:true`, but the grid contain should be loaded at once at the first request to the server.
5. There are no `autoFit` column property.